# How Paramterize Copy Activity to SQL DB with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to automatically update tables in  Azure SQL Database from another SQLDB with Azure Data Factory. At the moment, the only way to update the table Azure SQL Database is to physically select the table you want to update in Azure SQL Database, as shown here:

[image]

My configuration to automatically select a table the SQLDB that I want to copy to Azure SQL Database is as follows:

[image]

The parameters are as follows:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)
```

Can someone let me know how to configure my SINK and/or connection to automatically insert the table selected from SOURCE.

My SINK looks like the following:
[image]

And my connection looks like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone let me know how to configure my SINK and/or connection to
> automatically insert the table selected from SOURCE.

You can use **Edit option** in the SQL dataset.

**Create a dataset parameter for the sink table name**. In the SQL sink dataset **check the `Edit` checkbox in it and use the dataset parameter**. If you want, you can use dataset parameter for the database name also. Here I have given directly (dbo).

[image]

Now in the copy activity sink, **you can give the table name dynamically** from any pipeline parameter (give your parameter in this case) or any variable using the **dynamic content**.

[image]

Also, enable the **Auto create table** which will **create new table if the table with the given name not exists and if it exists it ignores creation and copies data to it**.

**My sample result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks again for reaching out . I'm going to test your solution in 10 minutes.

Comment: Hi @Patterson, did you try it?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, I did try it and it work perfectly thanks.